# IE9 randomly? not displaying content, failing links, etc?? CSS?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

Background info: I'm working on a public facing website for our company.  developing in VS2012, asp.net and vb.net, using some JS, some JQuery, and a decent amount of CSS.

Everything was looking great in our internal testing, until someone checked from home, where they only had IE 9.  Suddenly, big chunks of text within expanding panels weren't being displayed, the bottom of the page was missing in most cases, some links that call javascript functions don't do anything... It's so random that the only reason I think they're connected is that it only happens in IE9 (or probably before, though no one has looked.)

I tried setting the standards mode to edge in the web.config.  (tried setting it to IE10 as well, just to try) I've played with changing some positioning, heights in px instead of %, relative to fixed positioning, tried inserting the html5shiv, removing the gradients... nothing has changed.  Everything displays correctly, until it doesn't display at all.  When I was starting to see and research this last week, I thought I'd found an article somewhere that said there were limits on the CSS tags you could use in a page for IE9, but that number was WAY higher than anything I'm using, including both what's on the page directly, and incorporating the .css file.  The only other clue is that it looks like at the bottom, where the missing stuff starts, I also lose the gradient from the page background (so just a block of all white, however if I play with the size of the window, sometimes I can get this block to slide down, and I can see another line or two that was originally hidden...

Has anyone had issues like this?  The site works perfect in chrome, ff, IE10 and 11, several Linux browsers, opera, safari, from macs, pcs, and Linux boxes.  everything except this old IE 9.

HELP?

Answer (score 0):

Just a little hack fix I found, if anyone comes across this question looking for similar answers... I created a new css file implemented when IE9 browsers are detected, and I extended the min-height for the content of pages until every page displayed... the drawback is that on those longer pages, if the content isn't expanded, the footer still lies several scrolls down... but this only happens on the very content-lengthy pages, so while it isn't ideal, I guess it's good enough, if someone's ok with using outdated browser technology :/